# Math class exercises

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Considering, $x \in X$ we can assume the following about the power set: $2^x$ ($x$ being an element of the set $X$). Hence, we know that a function is injective if and only if we have for $x,y\in \mathbb R$, we have $f(x)=f(y)$. Hence, $2^x=2^y$, so then taking the logarithm of each side, we get $x=y$. This proves that the power set is injective.

I'm not sure this is right at all. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you know what $\;2^X\;$ denotes? It seems like you don't.

Comment: Just as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867506/how-to-prove-there-is-no-surjection) $\log x$ is meaningless, $2^x$ is meaningless; this set has nothing to do with real numbers. We could perfectly well have $X = \{\text{cat, dog, apple}\}$; so what does $2^{\text{apple}}$ mean?

Comment: @T.Bongers: Obviously, it means the power set of an apple.

Answer (score 9):

You are confused about the meaning of $2^X$. You seem to interpret it as the set of all elements of the form $2^x$ where $x\in X$. This is incorrect though. The set $2^X$ is the set of all subsets of $X$. Now that you know that, can you come up with an injective function from a set $X$ to the set of all subsets of $X$? Given an element $x\in X$, which subset of $X$ can you most naturally think of to associate with $x$?

Comment: I guess what I don't seem to understand is how we can go back and forth between an injection of functions and sets.

Comment: @user161367 What do you mean "injection of functions and sets"? An injection is a function with a very special property.

Comment: @T.Bongers, I think the proof is very straightforward that I'm not sure it's right. So the way I see it, is that 2^X is the set of all the subsets of X. So for any element x ∈ X, {x} ∈ 2^X. So if we define the function f to be f(x)={x} (for all x ∈ X) then we're done. But I'm not sure that the answer is that easy..

Comment: It IS that easy. Ittay Weiss's answer tried to lead you to this, with "which subset of $X$ can you most naturally think of to associate with $x$? (:

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is very good but has the problem that (by standard definitions) $2^X$ is not the set of subsets of X. It is the set of functions from the set X to the set 2. The set 2 being {0,1}.

In light of this there is a canonical bijection $F$ from $2^X$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$, the set of all subsets of X. For some  $g\in 2^X$ the bijection maps $F(g) = \{x|g(x)=1\}$

So this gives us a very simple injection where the element $x$ maps to a unique function. That function being the one which maps x to 1 and all other element of X to 0.

Comment: What you say is true, but in many context $2^X$ actually does denote the power set of $X$. Especially if these questions didn't come from a set theory related book, but rather from an analysis or algebra related topic.

Comment: Yes I agree but some of the comments from the other answer seem to show confusion about this. Also I think that notation is bad because it leaves $3^X$ undefined